# Can dependencies be installed with yum in .openshift/action_hooks/build?

Tags: openshift

I am using a DIY cartridge, and would like to use yum to install a dependency in the install stage (.openshift/action_hooks/build). Is this possible?

When I try, it fails with "Error: rpmdb open failed", and permission to use sudo is denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you would have to have root access to install packages via yum.  If there is a package that you would like installed, and can make a good case for it, you can either add it here (www.openshift.com/ideas) or file a bugzilla ticket here (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online)

Comment: My use case is managing js client dependencies with bower in a non-js app. This means having node and npm about at install time. I'm sure there must be a better way to do that then....

Comment: OK, so it turns out that the environment provides npm as a default. Which is nice and entirely unexpected. Oh, well, sorry to bother!