# Openshift Rails Scaling App Gem mysql2 fails to install

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, openshift

I have created a Openshift application on Rails 4, ruby 2, with MySQL 5.5, scaling.

When trying to deploy, I keep getting this error:

```
remote: Installing mysql2 (0.3.20)
remote: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote: checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
remote: checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
remote: checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
remote: checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
remote: checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
remote: checking for rb_intern3()... yes
remote: -----
remote: Using mysql_config at /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin/mysql_config
remote: -----
remote: checking for mysql.h... yes
remote: checking for errmsg.h... yes
remote: checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
remote: -----
remote: Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
remote: -----
remote: -----
remote: Setting libpath to /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql
remote: -----
remote: creating Makefile
remote:
remote: make "DESTDIR="
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o client.o -c client.c
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o infile.o -c infile.c
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o mysql2_ext.o -c mysql2_ext.c
remote: gcc -I. -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include/ruby/backward -I/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/include -I. -I/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/include/mysql -DHAVE_RUBY_THREAD_H -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CALL_WITHOUT_GVL -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_RB_WAIT_FOR_SINGLE_FD -DHAVE_RB_HASH_DUP -DHAVE_RB_INTERN3 -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H    -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -fPIC -m64 -o result.o -c result.c
remote: rm -f mysql2.so
remote: gcc -shared -o mysql2.so client.o infile.o mysql2_ext.o result.o -L. -L/opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/lib64 -L/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -m64  -lruby -L/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
remote: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
remote: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
remote: make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1
```

I tried doing the suggested here:
[Cannot install mysql2 gem on openshift scaled app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813780/cannot-install-mysql2-gem-on-openshift-scaled-app)
but it didn't work, I keep getting the error.